# Taking an array from localStorage, back to values

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm new to this so please be gentle.

I an on a course where we are being asked to store items in localStorage, which I have done. Now further through the course we need to take the data in local storage and upload it to Firebase realtime db, while also emailing out the response.

The trouble is, I know what I WANT to do but can't describe what i want to do, nor actually figure it out.

```
if (localStorage.getItem("items")) {
    products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
```

So I know this works and will get the items from localStorage, but how on earth would I turn them back into an object in order to then give constants to the name: price: quantity: values?

I think from that part I can figure out how to pass those to firebase and the postmark API's

Comment: What is your localstorage data? Localstorage data is already supposed to be a json object

Comment: If you console.log `products` after the line with JSON.parse - what will it log and what you want it to look like?

Comment: @DenizKaradağ It is supposed to be json string in localstorage, not json object. Btw what is `json object`?

Comment: `JSON.parse()` turns them back into an object. Why do you think you need to do something else?

Comment: It's probably an array of objects, so you may need to loop over the array to insert them into the DB.

Comment: It's not so much getting the data back using parse, but filtering out each value to assign a constant that I'm getting stuck with.

Comment: Not too obvious to be honest what exactly you are planning to do with parsed objects. Can you give an example? Like "I have array of objects that looks like that and I need to do this this this and they will look like that2"

Comment: @Barmar yes, we stringified the object into localstorage. In all honesty the project is way beyond the level of the course I am on so it's not unexpected I'm confused by it.

Comment: Can you share what you are storing in localStorage and how you are prepping it for that?

Comment: You should link documentation and things you have tried or relate to the issue, for example linking the firebase documentation you are using